# Android notification in status bar: use text instead of small icon?

Tags: android, android-notifications

With the [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html), there is the `setSmallIcon()` function to set icon to use in the status bar.

For my purpose, I don't want an icon, but rather I want text (numbers to be more precise), just like the battery level percentage indication that is put there by the system.

I can't see a way of doing this, and I have a sinking feeling that I will need to have a different icon for each and every possible number, including both positive and negative.  Please tell me that I'm wrong!

Comment: If your `minSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you can use `setSmallIcon(Icon)`, and you can create an `Icon` from dynamic sources (e.g., a `Bitmap` that you draw text into using a `Canvas`). Otherwise, AFAIK, you need to ship with icons for your possible numbers.

Comment: `minSdkVersion` is 16, only `targetSdkVersion` is 23.... :-0 seems a little unbelievable that it's not possible to do something simple like write text in the status bar.  Strewth!  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Once I have a bitmap how to go about setting it to `smallIcon?

Comment: I found the answer to my comment. It can be done using "setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bit_map))"